# Code analysis doesn't understand _In_opt_ parameter Annotation?

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis, sal

Looks like SAL bug. The code:

```
    PAAFILEFILTER_PROTECTED_FILE curFile = NULL;

     try
        {
            status = GetProtectedFile(FileIdInfo, instanceContext, &curFile);
            if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
            {
                TraceError("Can't GetProtectedFile with status: %!STATUS!\n", status);
                leave;
            }
         ...


    finally
    {
        if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            LogMessage(AAFILEFILTER_FILE_UNPROTECTED, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)FileIdInfo, sizeof(AAFILE_ID_INFORMATION));
        }
        else
        {
            TraceProtectedFile(curFile);
        }
    }
```

And code analysys give me [C6102 - Using variable from failed function call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C6102)&rd=true)

at line `TraceProtectedFile(curFile)`; but TraceProtectedFile have prototype

```
_In_opt_ PAAFILEFILTER_PROTECTED_FILE protectedFile
```

[_In_opt_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh916383.aspx)    mean `"_In_opt_ is the same as _In_, except that the input parameter is allowed to be NULL and, therefore, the function should check for this."` .. don't undestand if CA can't handle such simple things then what it can :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the way your error handling is structured, not the `_In_opt_` parameter.

I wouldn't be surprised if `leave`, when mixed with standard C++ exception handling, confuses SAL enough that it doesn't recognize that the `finally` will never be hit. `leave` isn't part of standard C++ exceptions and is MSVC-specific, intended for [structured exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb3kz605.aspx).

The good thing is that that SAL's confusion is a hint that other developers might be similarly surprised by error handling like this. You should probably consider moving the `GetProtectedFile` call outside of your `try`/`finally`, since all of that code assumes that curFile was initialized successfully:

```
PAAFILEFILTER_PROTECTED_FILE curFile = NULL;

status = GetProtectedFile(FileIdInfo, instanceContext, &curFile);
if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    TraceError("Can't GetProtectedFile with status: %!STATUS!\n", status);
    return; // Return whatever is appropriate here
}

// The rest of your code can assume curFile initialized successfully

try
{  
    ...
}
finally
{
    if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        LogMessage(AAFILEFILTER_FILE_UNPROTECTED, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)FileIdInfo, sizeof(AAFILE_ID_INFORMATION));
    }
    else
    {
        TraceProtectedFile(curFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with you... that is more cleaner. But still this is CA bug :)  C6102  must never be raised for  _In_opt_ parametr IMHO.